# How to set the result folder using command line parameter to nunit-console?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console, nunit-2.5

I am trying to run NUnit tests from command line and trying to save the results under `TestResults` folder. I have tried using following commands, but nothing has created the test results under intended folder. Rather the test results got created under the current running folder only!

```
cmd /k nunit3-console.exe test\bin\Debug\test.dll --where cat=test  --labels=All --work=TestResults --out=TestResult.txt --result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2

cmd /k nunit3-console.exe test\bin\Debug\test.dll --where cat=test  --labels=All --work=TestResults --out=TestResults\TestResult.txt --result=TestResults\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2

cmd /k nunit3-console.exe test\bin\Debug\test.dll --where cat=test  --labels=All --out=TestResults\TestResult.txt --result=TestResults\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2
```

Likewise I have also tried changing the default test result filename from `TestResult.xml` & `TestResult.txt` to `Sample.xml` & `Sample.txt` by updating the `--result` & `--out` parameters, but no luck.

Comment: The top version should work. Does the TestResults folder exist?

Comment: Yes, TestResults folder is there. Still it's creating the result outside only, not inside the TestResults folder. Moreover it's just creating TestResult.xml only, TestResult.txt is missing!

Comment: Sounds buggy - I suggest you post a bug report in the nunit-console repo. I'd recommend running with the `--trace=Debug` option to generate logs, and include those in your bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The `--out` option has been around for a long time. It causes any output from the test, which would normally go to the console to be written to the file specified.

The `--result` option replaces the old NUnit V2 `--xml` option, and indicates where an XML output file should be written.

I think your problem arises from the fact that your tests produce no output "which would normally go to the console." That's because NUnit 3 sends almost all test output to the XML result file. The only console output that is produced is output written to stderr or created using `TestContext.Error` or `TestContext.Progress`.

It's possible to imagine a change to NUnit whereby use of `--out` would **stop** the output from being incorporated in the XML file, but that would be breaking for a lot of people.

Bottom line: once the output was added to the XML result file, the `--out` parameter became somewhat useless. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Ohh my bad :)

I was missing double == after CAT which caused this issue.

```
cmd /k nunit3-console.exe test\bin\Debug\test.dll --where cat==test --labels=All --work=TestResults --out=TestResult.txt --result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2
```

Above one fixed my issue and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the **--work** option.

Ex.: `nunit3-console ./bin/release/myproject.dll --work=./MyTestFolder`

The path of your test will be `./MyTestFolder/TestResult.xml`